# Spring does not connect to mysql database using JPA datasource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, datasource

I have a spring project and i want my tables created by hibernate but i think my app can't connect to database. I changed my datasource db url to be wrong and there is no exception at all. When i change packagesToScan property to a value which does not exist, still there is no exceptions. So the problem is that spring does not try to connect to the db.

Here is my root-context.xml.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:application.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.istiletisim.test" />
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<task:annotation-driven />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>test2</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>1234</value>
    </property>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxIdle">
        <value>1000</value>
    </property>
    <property name="testWhileIdle">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="testOnBorrow">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="validationQuery">
        <value>SELECT 1</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxActive">
        <value>50</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxWait">
        <value>1000</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.istiletisim.test.model" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

And web.xml file here :

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does your `root-context.xml` is getting read from `web.xml` as you told your changes are not reflecting and not causing any exceptions either?

Comment: Yes, when i change entityManagerFactory class to a wrong value i get an exception. I added my web.xml file to question.

Comment: And also when i change datasource class to a different one like "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" it takes longer to initialize the app.

Comment: I doubt that it isn't connecting, judging from your description your configuration isn't used (or what you posted isn't the configuration as you use it!). I would also suggestion using something like HikariCP instead of commons-dbcp or c3p0 (both are old and not really maintained anymore and have performance issues).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i'll check it. But the configuration is as in the post and i still cant make it work. Maybe there is something wrong with the other files. I don't think so though.

Comment: I solved it. I didn't have any classes that are autowired to my repository classes. So spring did not initialized my repository and model classes. I added an autowired repository to my controller and then it worked..